# How can I filter all GitHub pull requests for a specific target branch

Tags: git, github, pull-request

I'm working on a GitHub repo with lots of branches and pull requests.

Let's say, for example, that I have the following pull requests:

- `a` to branch `X`
- `b` to branch `X`
- `c` to branch `Y`
- `d` to branch `X`
- `e` to branch `Y`.

Is there a way to find all the pull requests that are targeted for branch `X` (i.e. `a -> X`, `b -> X`, `d -> X`)?

Answer (score 173, accepted):

Yes, you can do it.

In Github's terminology the "to branch" is "base"
So the search phrase is: `is:open is:pr base:X`

Official description: [Search based on branch names](https://docs.github.com/en/github/searching-for-information-on-github/searching-issues-and-pull-requests#search-by-branch-name)

Optionally you can add `is:merged` or `is:unmerged` filters as well.

Comment: this is a new feature! more details at: 
https://help.github.com/articles/searching-issues/#search-based-on-branch-names

Comment: Unfortunately this matches all branches starting with X. Anyone know how to search for a specific branch, not a prefix?

Comment: To specify a `head` branch, meaning: the branch the PR is coming FROM, not merging TO, use `head:my_branch` instead of `base:my_branch`. See: https://docs.github.com/en/github/searching-for-information-on-github/searching-issues-and-pull-requests#search-by-branch-name.

Comment: Important: the searches here (ex: `repo:my_username/my_repository is:open is:pr base:my_branch`) MUST be done in the PR search bar here (https://github.robot.car/pulls), NOT in the generic GitHub search bar at the top-left of nearly any GitHub page!

Comment: I expounded upon this, and wrote custom Chrome searches. Here's my answer with how: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66287268/4561887.

Comment: Kind of stupid that you can only search branches BEGINNING with a search query. Would love to just be able to search contains.

Answer (score 19):

### How to search for PRs by "from (`head`) branch", by "to (`base`) branch", and by author, *including* doing this using custom Chrome search engines you can quickly trigger in your search bar:

*Note: the below searches for PRs (Pull Requests) on GitHub are intended to be done in the PR search bar here (https://github.com --> "Pull requests" at top) (direct link: https://github.com/pulls), **not** in the generic GitHub search bar at the top-left of nearly any GitHub page, although they might work there too.*

See also my answer here: [Can I search github labels with logical operator OR?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29136057/can-i-search-github-labels-with-logical-operator-or/61618255#61618255)

In GitHub lingo, the branch you are merging FROM is the `head` branch, and the branch you are merging TO is the `base` branch. See here: https://docs.github.com/en/github/searching-for-information-on-github/searching-issues-and-pull-requests#search-by-branch-name. I'm not sure why they didn't choose `from_branch` and `to_branch` instead, as that would have been easier to remember.

### 1. Find all PRs FROM `my_branch` by using the search string `head:my_branch`:

```
is:open is:pr archived:false head:my_branch
```

Optionally, specify a repository too:

```
is:open is:pr archived:false repo:some_username/some_repository head:my_branch
```

### 2. Find all PRs merging inTO `my_branch` by using the search string `base:my_branch`:

```
is:open is:pr archived:false base:my_branch
```

Optionally, specify a repository too:

```
is:open is:pr archived:false repo:some_username/some_repository base:my_branch
```

### 3. References:

1. From the official GitHub documentation: https://docs.github.com/en/github/searching-for-information-on-github/searching-issues-and-pull-requests#search-by-branch-name:

   > **Search by branch name**
   >
   > You can filter pull requests based on the branch they came from (the "head" branch) or the branch they are merging into (the "base" branch).
   >
   > ```
   > Qualifier               Example  
   > ---------------------   -------------------------------------------------
   > `head:HEAD_BRANCH`      `head:change is:closed is:unmerged` matches pull 
   >                         requests opened from branch names beginning with 
   >                         the word "change" that are closed.
   >
   > `base:BASE_BRANCH`      `base:gh-pages` matches pull requests that are 
   >                         being merged into the gh-pages branch.
   > ```
2. [@Andor Dávid's answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32293984/4561887)

### 4. GOING FURTHER: Add custom Google Chrome search engines for GitHub searches

For those who don't know, the Chrome browser allows you to create custom search engines. If I go to my browser search bar and type `gto` followed by <kbd>Space</kbd> or <kbd>Tab</kbd>, then type in my branch name, `my_branch`, I see this. I am literally searching for all open PRs merging TO branch `my_branch`, using my custom search engine triggered by the `gto` shortcut I set up:

[image]

Here's how to configure those:

In Chrome, click on 3 dots in top-right --> Settings --> Search engine (in left pane) --> "Manage search engines" --> under "Other search engines", click the "Add" button. Set it up like this:
[image]

Click "Save" when done. Here are 3 of my favorites:

1. **Search for GitHub PRs merging TO a given branch**:

   1. Search engine: `GitHub PRs merging TO branch`
   2. Keyword: `gto`
   3. URL with `%s` in place of query: `https://github.com/pulls?q=is%3Aopen+is%3Apr+archived%3Afalse+base%3A%s`
2. **Search for GitHub PRs merging FROM a given branch**:

   1. Search engine: `GitHub PRs merging FROM branch`
   2. Keyword: `gfrom`
   3. URL with `%s` in place of query: `https://github.com/pulls?q=is%3Aopen+is%3Apr+archived%3Afalse+head%3A%s`
3. **Search for GitHub PRs BY a certain author**:

   1. Search engine: `GitHub PRs BY this User`
   2. Keyword: `gby`
   3. URL with `%s` in place of query: `https://github.com/pulls?q=is%3Aopen+is%3Apr+author%3A%s+archived%3Afalse+`

The way you figure out what to add for the URL search string is actually quite simple: you just go to GitHub and do a search manually using GitHub's tools, then you copy and paste the URL, replacing the search string you'd like to search for with `%s` in the custom Chrome Search engine URL. That's it! This process works for any and all websites which store their search variables into the URL once you do a custom search on their website, which is many, if not most, websites with search capability.

<sub>Keywords: Google chrome / browser custom search engines for GitHub PRs</sub>

Answer (score 14):

As of 2016-01-10 this has been added to the gh search bar api, see next answer.

Original accepted (and now outed answer) left un-edited.

---

### Currently Not Available via Web Interface

GitHub currently does not provide a way to filter pull-requests by their target
branch through their web interface. Instead, all you currently get is just the
entire list of pull-requests with the names of the topic branches:

[image: GitHub Pull-Request UI]

Clicking into a pull-request will show the target branch, but that doesn't
really help you do any of the filtering that you want to do.

### You Can Use the GitHub REST API Instead

It is possible to filter pull-requests by using the [GitHub REST API](https://developer.github.com/v3/pulls/#list-pull-requests),
however:

```
GET /repos/:owner/:repo/pulls?base=:branch
```

That should show you all the open pull-requests for the repo `:owner/:repo`,
filtered by requests that target `:branch` as their base branch. From the
documentation:

> Filter pulls by base branch name. Example: `gh-pages`.

#### Example Using cURL

If you have `curl` available, you can test this on a public repo from the
command line. Here, the repo being queried is this one (https://github.com/codecombat/codecombat), and we are getting all pull requests from `base` branch (the branch the PRs are merging TO) named `master`, and then storing the results into a **pulls.json** file we will parse through next.

```
curl https://api.github.com/repos/codecombat/codecombat/pulls?base=master > \
pulls.json
```

That will return a JSON response of the following form, now stored inside file **pulls.json**:

```javascript
[
  {
    "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/codecombat/codecombat/pulls/879",
    "id": 14955421,
    "html_url": "https://github.com/codecombat/codecombat/pull/879",
    "head": {
      "label": "DanielRodriguezRivero:patch-4",
      "ref": "patch-4",
      "sha": "baff84f0aeee12f23e3608558ae5341a0b5f939b",
      "repo": {
        "id": 16202384,
        "name": "codecombat",
        "full_name": "DanielRodriguezRivero/codecombat"
      }
    },
    "base": {
      "label": "codecombat:master",
      "ref": "master",
      "sha": "5e2f3ac7cb731a6e40e81737a5122c7fe1b746d3",
      "repo": {
        "id": 15193430,
        "name": "codecombat",
        "full_name": "codecombat/codecombat"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Each object in the array is a pull request (PR), filtered by the `base=target` branch, which we specified to be `master` in our `curl` command above.

The JSON actually contains much more information than this; I've just removed most of it to show the relevant parts for this question.

#### Parsing the cURL Response

You could probably write a Python/Ruby/PHP/Whatever script to then parse out the `html_url` property of each pull-request and list it on the command line. For example, here's a simple Ruby script that will parse the output of a JSON response saved from the `curl` output:

```ruby
require 'json'

json = JSON.parse(File.read('./pulls.json'))
pulls = json.map { |pull| { title: pull['title'], url: pull['html_url'] } }

pulls.each do |pull|
  puts pull.values
  puts
end
```

Which outputs the following:

```
$ ruby parser.rb
Update es-ES.coffee
https://github.com/codecombat/codecombat/pull/879

Fix deltas referring to last system saved
https://github.com/codecombat/codecombat/pull/874

Refactor getNameById and add naming to systems in deltas
https://github.com/codecombat/codecombat/pull/866

Traducido varios textos del fichero es-ES.coffe al espa├▒ol de Espa├▒a
https://github.com/codecombat/codecombat/pull/865

Anon name collide
https://github.com/codecombat/codecombat/pull/834
```

Comment: I added a note that this answer is now outdated, hesitant to delete your entire first section.

Answer (score 1):

Now that the [GitHub CLI](https://cli.github.com/) is available, here's how you would do it for a given repository.

You can install the `gh` CLI following the [appropriate instructions](https://github.com/cli/cli#installation) for your OS and preferred package manager.

I use the `cli/cli` repo to demonstrate:

`gh pr list --base trunk -R cli/cli`

Output:

```
#3045  [hackday] mergeconflict                                                  hackday2102
#3044  Isolate test suite from environment variables                            env-tests
#3042  Remove functionality to add, view and edit binary files in gists         g14a:bug/gist-binary-files
#3023  Issue/pr create: exit with nonzero status code when "Cancel" was chosen  cancel-error-status
#3018  Add `pr create --body-file` flag                                         castaneai:pr-create-body-file
#3010  Add `api --cache` flag                                                   api-cache
#3008  Add interactive select in gist view                                      ganboonhong:interactive-gist-view
#2997  Feature/add files to gist                                                g14a:feature/add-files-to-gist
#2991  Repo create tweaks                                                       repo-create-prompt-change
#2953  Add `repo list` command                                                  cristiand391:add-repo-list
#2923  [WIP] first round of actions support                                     actions
#2728  Better completions                                                       rsteube:better-completions
#2261  pr status: show number of approvals                                      despreston:des/approval-count
#2160  Sign Windows .exes in a post-build hook                                  mbpreble:sign-windows-executables
#2080  store gh config in %APPDATA% on windows os                               RozzaysRed:appdata_configPath
```