# GitHub: How to find pull request(s) that will merge a particular branch name?

Tags: github

I have a particular git branch name, and I want to find the open pull request(s) (if any) that will merge that branch into a base branch (most typically `master`/`main`).

How can I use GitHub's web UI to find that pull request?

- The `Pull requests` tab for a given project currently offers the ability to filter by any of Author, Label, Projects, Milestones, Reviews, or Assignee -- but not by branch.

Related existing question: [How can I filter all GitHub pull requests for a specific target branch](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20547198/12484), which covers how to find pull request(s) based on on a particular *target* (base) branch name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done on the Pull Requests tab by searching on the term:

```
head:myBranchName is:pr is:open
```

(Where `myBranchName` is the name of your branch.)

Reference: https://docs.github.com/en/search-github/searching-on-github/searching-issues-and-pull-requests#search-by-branch-name

Comment: for my case, i needed `is:pr is:closed base:staging` to get all PR that were merged into staging